# SASS: generated CSS not optimal

Tags: sass

I am trying to learn SASS. I got this snippet working but the generated css is awful in my opinion. I would like all this css to go in te same .container{ }. Not three different as shown below.

SASS:

```
   .container{
         @extend %clearfix;
         @extend %text-truncate;
         @include border-radius(10px);
     }
```

Genereted css:

```
.container{
...clear fix
}
.container{
...text-truncate
}
.container{
...clear border-radius
}
```

What I want:

```
.container{
...clear fix
...text-truncat
...clear border-radius
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the nature of `@extend`.  If you change your extend classes to ordinary classes, the way it works the way it does is revealed.

```
@mixin my-mixin() {
    padding: 1em;
}

.a {
    color: red;
}

.b {
    border: 1px solid;
}

.foo {
    @extend .a;
    @extend .b;
    @include my-mixin();
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.a, .foo {
  color: red;
}

.b, .foo {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.foo {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Using an *extend only* class simply suppresses the name from the output.  If your extend classes are not intended for reuse, then they are better suited as a mixin.

See also:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/27910/26722

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I started with mixins but read that a mixin that does not take any parameter is wrong.